# Any in-built method to only know if two lists are different?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections, comparison

I have to compare two lists and **only** know if they contain same values or not. I do not intend to do anything with the differences.

What would be the best way to achieve this in C#?

I know I can loop the lists but want to know if theres any in-built LINQ/extenstion method to achieve this which provides better performance. Did try Except/Intersect, but don't know if they are the most suitable ones to achieve this.

Update: The lists won't have any duplicates within them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you want to handle duplicates? For example, would you count { 2, 1, 1 } as being the same as { 1, 2 }? (I'm assuming that the order is irrelevant... otherwise just use `SequenceEqual`.)

Assuming you only care about "sets" effectively, here are two options:

A quick and dirty way:

```
if (!list1.Except(list2).Any() && !list2.Except(list1).Any())
```

A slightly cleaner way:

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(list1); // Adjust case accordingly
if (set.SetEquals(list2))
{
    // Lists were equal
}
```

One thing to consider: if you're only interested in treating them as sets, you might want to use a set representation to start with, instead of a list...

Comment: You could just use `SetEquals` rather than `SymmetricExceptWith`/`Any`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks, missed that, doh :)

Comment: There wouldn't be any duplicates in any of the lists.It would be like {1, 2 ,3} and {2, 3, 4}.